# Turn Custom Post Title into external link

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, loop

I created a **Custom Post Type** called **News**, which supports **Title**, **Editor**, **Thumbnail** and **Custom Fields**. One of the Custom Fields is `URL`. What I need now is to turn the `Title` in a external link in the loop, using the URL provided in the `URL` Custom Field. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to replace the regular permalink or just add `<a href>` around the title text?

Comment: I want to replace the regular permalink by the URL Custom Field link.

Comment: I found this plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/screenshots/) wich works with Custom Post Types too.

Comment: You can use my code from the other answer and use `post_type_link` as filter. This will work with custom post types. I made an update there.